# NewRow key binding being ignored

Tags: front-end

I have a slightly funky issue which is likely OS specific but which I haven't been able to patch. I believe since upgrading to 11.2 the key-event for adding a new row to a grid isn't firing.

I looked at my `"KeyEventTranslations"`:

```
FEFindFileOnPath["KeyEventTranslations.tr"]

"/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/TextResources/Macintosh/KeyEventTranslations.tr"
```

And its still the system-level binding. And if I look at the values for all `"Return"`-related key events:

```
KeySelect[$FEKeyEvents, Not@*FreeQ["Return"]]

<|KeyEvent["Return", Modifiers -> {Shift}] :> 
  HoldComplete["HandleShiftReturn"], 
 KeyEvent["Return", Modifiers -> {Command}] :> 
  HoldComplete[Evaluate[All]], 
 KeyEvent["Return", Modifiers -> {Option}] :> 
  HoldComplete["SimilarCellBelow"], 
 KeyEvent["Return"] :> HoldComplete["Linebreak"], 
 KeyEvent["Return", Modifiers -> {Control}] :> 
  HoldComplete["NewRow"]|>
```

I find that the only binding for Control-Return is `"NewRow"`. Calling `FrontEndTokenExecute["NewRow"]` *does* work, so clearly the issue is that the binding isn't being called at all. Instead it only acts as if I called `"Return"`.

I know that `"Control"` is active, as using:

```
CurrentValue["ModifierKeys"] // Dynamic
```

activates when I press it down.

I'm on macOS version 10.13.3. Can anyone help me figure out why?

Comment: Works fine on Win7 V11.2.

Comment: Have you modified menu commands?

Comment: @CarlWoll Nope. And the menu command works fine. It never even shows that the highlight in the menu that would show the `"MenuCommand"` had been called.